# How to fix node filesystem write function?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

The function writeFile is Identified but doesn't work in ubuntu 18.04; however, it does work in my local environment.

but it doesn't write.

I added full permissions to the folder.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile( 'test.json', 'dfsdfsd', function(err){
        if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('data appended');
        console.log(fs.writeFile);
});
```

---

Result

```
root@laravel-dropin:/var/www/html/resources# node js/test.js 
data appended
[Function: writeFile]
```

Comment: I think the problem is because 'fs' has not been installed correctly

Comment: ```
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, access '/var/www/html/node_modules/fs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
This works instead writeFile function

```
let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('secret.json');

        // write some data with a base64 encoding
        writeStream.write(s);

        // the finish event is emitted when all data has been flushed from the stream
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {  
            console.log('wrote all data to file');
        });

        // close the stream
        writeStream.end();
```